# Trying to understand how undcl works (From K&R book - chapter 5-12 Complicated Declarations)

Tags: c

i am confused about how undcl works. Here is the code given from the K&R book

```
....
int main()
{
    int type;
    char temp[MAXTOKEN];

    while(gettoken() != EOF) {
        strcpy(out, token);
        while((type = gettoken()) != '\n')
        if(type == PARENS || type == BRACKETS)
            strcat(out, token);
        else if (type == '*') {
            sprintf(temp, "(*%s)",out);
            strcpy(out, temp);
        } else if (type == NAME) {
            sprintf(temp, "%s %s", token, out);
            strcpy(out, temp);
        } else
            printf("invalid input at %s\n",token);
}
    return 0;
}
....
```

what am i suppose to input here?
i tried typing the word to word declaration in the input but it doesn't seem to work

example i run the program and i type this:

argv: pointer to pointer to char

and it only shows 'invalid input at argv' error

Comment: It would surprise me if the code in K&R was actually wrong, but it seems to me that the colon following `argv` will be a token of its own, with type `':'`. And that type isn't handled in the code. Try it without the colon and see what happens?

Answer (score 2):

The book gives you an example of the input it'll accept immediately above the code, namely:

```
x () * [] * () char
```

which is "an abbreviated input syntax" meaning "x is a function returning a pointer to an array of pointers to functions returning char."

Try entering that, and you should get the following output:

```
char (*(*x())[])()
```